# Replacement stereo has no sound

Tags: electrical, audio, kia, sportage

I swapped the stereo/media-centre out in a Kia Sportage for a secondhand one that is 1 model out.
The original units NAND died locking it into a boot-loop; but the radio/audio continued to work (so I know the speakers and wiring are still fine).

The only external difference between the two units is a decrease in the model number and the new unit has a 14amp negative ground (original unit was 5amp negative ground)

Internally the units have an identical board serial number; but the replacement unit has a capacitor in the blank space of the original and a black block marked amp; I assume this is the issue but am not sure how to resolve it.

The rear connections are identical on both units

[image: KiaSportage Audio Motherboard]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image: new unit amp]
[image: new unit right rear]
[image: new unit left rear]
[image: newunitinternals]

Comment: Maybe the replacement was originally connected to an external amplifier.  Are there menu options to enable/disable the speaker outputs?

Comment: Can you add a photo of the rear of both?

Comment: Added some more photos; the rear connections are identical on both units

Comment: The bigger question here is, how do you know the new stereo works in the first place?

Comment: It's a good question; the DAB/GPS/Standard radio tuner/Screen/Settings/Navigation/bluetooth etc all work fine. Its just the audio output. 
I'm having to work on the assumption that it works unless I can work out which of the pins is audio output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your additional photos, I believe my comment about one of them being used with an external amplifier is correct.

The new stereo has a built-in amplifier for directly driving speakers, whereas the original one has this circuity missing.  I would presume therefor that the original stereo connects to an audio power amplifier that is installed in your vehicle.

The loudspeaker outputs will be these unused pins on one of the connectors -

[image]

The wiring harness installed in your vehicle obviously has the loudspeakers connected to the power amplifier instead.

Hopefully it is just a matter of telling the new stereo to use the audio line outputs instead of the loud speaker outputs.  Do you have the operators manual for the new stereo?  Have you looked through the setting menus for the stereo to see if the output can be selected as I mentioned in my earlier comment?

Have you tried scanning the QR code on the back of the stereo to see if that gets you the manual for the stereo?

Comment: Informations scarce; it all came to nought anyway as it was overheating.
Thanks for the answer